# How to maintain a single ssh connection for multiple remote script executions?

Tags: python, bash, shell, ssh, scp

I have a folder in system A which contains millions of files,and i have system B in the same network.

Computer A ---> /home/nsadmin/Folder   -- 192.168.150.90

Computer B ---> /home/nsadmin/automate.sh  -- 192.168.150.91

Suppose in my Folder directory all the million files are dumped.And what iam doing now is

```
1 echo "Sending the files to Computer B"
2 scp -r /home/nsadmin/$folder_name nsadmin@192.168.150.91:/home/nsadmin/$folder_name
3 ssh nsadmin@192.168.150.91 "sh /home/nsadmin/$folder_name/automation.sh $folder_name"
4 rm -rf $folder_name/
```

From the above script what iam doing is

- Line 1 --> Echo Statement
- Line 2 --> Copiying the entire content of folder to Computer B
- Line 3 --> Remotely executing the script which runs taking folder_name as argument
- Line 4 --> Removing the folder from computer A

This seems very bad programming.

So what my idea is to maintain 1 single ssh connection and pass the each file to machine B which the connection is still on..

I will explain you clearly

```
ssh to remote machine open
 --- subtask which should run in a loop till all the files in folder are done
 --- subtask is copying each file to remote machine and running the automate.sh script with argument as file_name not folder_name,(logic i will modify)
 --- After all the files are copyed done the loop
ssh to remote machine closed
```

Problems i faced with my logic :

1. Large time taken for all the files to copy
2. No estimate of time remaiining for all files to copy
3. Multiple ssh connections
4. Space Problem in system B
5. System B is more like a worker which has some logic and it holds less space.
6. Automation is difficult with this ssh connections

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem which i explaied.? If any one didnt understand the questions please comment.

My Requirement in small pseudo code:

```
for i in $(find /home/nsadmin/Folder -type f);do
   scp -r /home/nsadmin/$i nsadmin@192.168.150.91:/home/nsadmin/$i
   ssh nsadmin@192.168.150.91 "sh /home/nsadmin/automation.sh $i"
done
```

Comment: From what a can tell you only use 2 ssh connections for the script, which isn't so bad.

Comment: No Actually i want to make it end to end like taking each file at a time and sending to other machine do some job and then put the results in DB.Overall idea is to send same file to 5 other systems as well to do parallel operation.If i copy files to machine `B` , then again i need to copy to `C` `D` `E`

Comment: to copy large amount of data I suggest using `rsync`.  In addition instead of making five computers remote accessible. why not using one server and pull the data with each computer?

Comment: I have a server, but i want to send the same file to each of 5 machines parallelly and after 1 worker done its job,send sencond file and it should not wait for other machines to complete its job.

Comment: Pinging random users who perhaps helped you in the past is not acceptable here.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to run these automation jobs continuously, I'd recommend using [celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/). Celery allows you to create a queue of tasks and distribute them to workers. You can even schedule the tasks to run at specific times like a cron job. You can create workers on separate machines if you want, but beware that your system might not be partition tolerant if you do this. Another software to look into for configuring and installing software on multiple machines is [ansible](https://www.ansible.com/). You can write an [ansible playbook](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks.html) to configure and install software on your worker machines so that they are ready to begin doing work. This way you don't have to set them up by hand every time.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ControlMaster`. It will open only single TCP connection for all the commands/scps you will issue. It is very simple to set up in `~/.ssh/config` add:

```
Host 192.168.150.91
  ControlMaster auto
  ControlPath ~/.ssh/sockets/%C
```

Then just run your pseudocode without any modification and it will execute much faster (over single TCP connection).